# Problems with importing Python library in VSC

Tags: python, visual-studio

I installed two Python libraries using *pip* in Visual Studio Code:

1. Pillow,
2. opencv - python.

Both installations were successful and they can be seen after the command *pip list*.
[image: pip list]

I have a problem however when I try to import these libraries. My code is very simple

```
from PIL import Image
```

or in the second case

```
import cv2
```

Unfortunately neither the first one nor the second one works. I get the following error
[image: cv2 error]
[image: PIL error]

I use Visual Studio Code, v.1.29.1

Answer (score 1):

If you run a python update, the previous version will not be uninstalled on windows, but the 2 versions will have a common management.
If a library was already present on the old version and appears to be the most up-to-date, it will remain in the old lib directory. Visual Studio may not handle this thing well.

Try checking if image and cv2 are in the lib directory of the latest python version.
Otherwise check if you have updated the python path on visual studio.